# How do you stop a dynamically loaded form from submitting with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an AJAX login system. Right now, when the user clicks on a link, the login form is dynamically loaded when the person clicks on a "log in" link. Since I'm using AJAX for this, I want to prevent the form from actually submitting when the submit button is clicked. I tried the following code as part of my load function, and the form loads correctely, but the form still submits normally.

```
$('#loginBox').load('loginform.php');
$('#loginBox form').submit(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**jQuery.load is an asynchronous function.**

This means that the form may not be available (yet) when you try to match "#loginBox form".
To make sure your code is executed after the form is loaded, you must pass your code as a callback function to load.

```
$('#loginBox').load("form.html", function() {
    $('#loginBox form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Btw - In your case it does not matter wether you use **event.preventDefault()** or **return false**. They will both prevent your form from being submitted. (See [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false))

Answer (score 3):

Add return false to prevent the default behavior:

```
$('#loginBox form').submit(function(event) {
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#loginBox form').submit(function(event) {
return false;
});
```